# Spring Integration without OSGi?

Tags: spring-integration

Some years ago we deployed several OSGi-based Spring Integration (SI) applications in Virgo. However, apparently SI has moved away from OSGi. So, in absence of Virgo container, what is best way to run an SI app in production now? Say, a simple app that monitors a file system location & loads file data into Oracle? Is it just `java -jar`?

Comment: You could use [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

Comment: OK. My impression from docs was that the goal of Spring Boot is fast, easy development; like, bootstrapping a new project. Is it also designed for production runtime?

Comment: Yes, Spring Boot is also for production software.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) makes it easy to create stand-alone, production-grade Spring based Applications that you can "just run". You can run a small production applications on it, you can consider using [Spring Cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) then.

If you are looking for a container then think about [SpringSource Tc Server](https://spring.io/blog/2010/03/10/introducing-springsource-tc-server-2-0) - based on [Pivotal Tc Server](http://pivotal.io/) (an enterprise version of Apache Tomcat) as a platform. This is the drop-in replacement for Apache Tomcat that's optimized for Spring.